# OpenFire Plugin: Sending custom message packet

Tags: java, xml, plugins, openfire

From my OpenFire plugin, I want to send a packet that looks like:

```
<message to="..." from="server">
    <fredselement xmlns="mynamespace">
        <someelement>"....."</someelement>
        <more>"......"</more>
    </fredselement>
</message>
```

I can send a normal message packet using:

```
org.xmpp.packet.Message message = new org.xmpp.packet.Message();
message.setTo(toJid);
message.setFrom(fromJid);
message.setSubject("subject");
message.setBody("body");      
router.route(message);
```

What is the best way to go about creating this custom packet object?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add your custom elements to the message like so.

```
Element fredsElem = message.addChildElement("fredselement", "mynamespace");
fredsElem.addChildElement("someelement");
fredsElem.addChildElement("more");
```